# Relational ActiveRecord ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I just post because I can no longer think, I am running in circles since this morning, I am really not far from succeeding the config of my database but I really can not think.
Let me explain: I have employees who can create meals, it's meals are composed of menu which are themselves composed of ingredients. Everything seems pretty tight because I can create meals for employees and a menu but when I do save, I have a rollback that tells me "`ActiveRecord :: NotNullViolation: SQLite3 :: ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: meals. Created_at: INSERT INTO "meals" DEFAULT VALUES` "

I suspect it is a relational problem but I do not find it

DB schema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170814112143) do

  create_table "ces", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "company_name"
    t.integer "employes_number"
    t.string "pdg"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "created_meals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "meal_id"
    t.integer "employe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["employe_id"], name: "index_created_meals_on_employe_id"
    t.index ["meal_id"], name: "index_created_meals_on_meal_id"
  end

  create_table "employes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "service"
    t.string "paiment"
    t.integer "note"
    t.string "status"
    t.integer "ce_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["ce_id"], name: "index_employes_on_ce_id"
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "category"
    t.boolean "allergen"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "meals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.string "place"
    t.integer "note"
    t.integer "menu_id"
    t.integer "employes_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["employes_id"], name: "index_meals_on_employes_id"
    t.index ["menu_id"], name: "index_meals_on_menu_id"
  end

  create_table "menus", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.float "unit_price"
    t.boolean "supply"
    t.integer "ingredients_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["ingredients_id"], name: "index_menus_on_ingredients_id"
  end

end
```

Relations :

```
class Ce < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employes
end
class CreatedMeal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :employe
end
class Employe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ce
  has_many :created_meals
end
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menus
end
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  has_many :employes
end
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients
  belongs_to :meal
end
```

### employes = Employe.all => OK

### ingredients = Ingredient.all => OK

### menu = Menu.new(name: "Les lazgnes du lundi", quantity: 6, unit_price: 5, supply: true) => OK

### menu.ingredients = ingredients => OK

irb(main):006:0> menu.save! =>

```
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "menus" DEFAULT VALUES
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: menus.created_at: INSERT INTO "menus" DEFAULT VALUES
    from (irb):6
```

### meal = Meal.new(date: Time.now, place: 5, note: 0) => OK

### meal.employes = employes => OK

### meal.menu = menu => OK

meal.save! =>

```
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Ce Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ces".* FROM "ces" WHERE "ces"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Ce Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ces".* FROM "ces" WHERE "ces"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "menus" DEFAULT VALUES
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: menus.created_at: INSERT INTO "menus" DEFAULT VALUES
    from (irb):12
```

Comment: Your associations between `Meal` and `Menu` are wrong. You have `belongs_to :menu` in `Meal`, which is correct but you have `belongs_to :meal` in `Menu` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem in:

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :meals # not belongs_to :meal
end
```

Because it imposible when to model linked this belongs_to in both way!

Comment: no it is the same
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `meal_id`

Comment: In any case, I want a meal to contain only one menu

Comment: In that case you should look to has_one association

Comment: Ok it looks like it's better but I still can not save.
The problem comes from above because it is the menu that I can not save

Comment: irb(main):006:0> menu.save
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `menu_id`
irb(main):006:0> menu.save!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "menus" DEFAULT VALUES
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: menus.created_at: INSERT INTO "menus" DEFAULT VALUES
 from (irb):6

Comment: If it's possible try to reset you db (develop DB) because it's seem like you have constraint in DB but not reflection on your data.

Comment: I am completely lost, I have to revisit all my tables, I am a beginner so I learn ;-) thank you very much for your help in any case

Comment: I thought you now what is reset DB (it drop all your table and create it again) And this empty db you have problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have redrawed my tables, this time I think the organization is good, but I can not get them a list of ingredients to my menu when I made menu.ingredients I get an error :

```
irb(main):003:0> menu.ingredients
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :ingredients_list in model Menu
    from (irb):3
```

so if I remove the s: menu.ingredient it tells me well "want to tell you ingredients?" I feel that there is not only the belongs_to or has_many which one of the effect on the join tables, I am wrong?
schema.rb
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170814204549) do

```
  create_table "business_companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "company_name"
    t.integer "employes_number"
    t.string "pdg"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "employes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "service"
    t.string "paiment"
    t.integer "note"
    t.string "status"
    t.integer "business_company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["business_company_id"], name: "index_employes_on_business_company_id"
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "category"
    t.boolean "allergen"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ingredients_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "ingredient_id"
    t.integer "menu_id"
    t.index ["ingredient_id"], name: "index_ingredients_lists_on_ingredient_id"
    t.index ["menu_id"], name: "index_ingredients_lists_on_menu_id"
  end

  create_table "meals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.string "place"
    t.integer "note"
    t.integer "menu_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["menu_id"], name: "index_meals_on_menu_id"
  end

  create_table "menus", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.float "unit_price"
    t.boolean "supply"
    t.integer "employe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["employe_id"], name: "index_menus_on_employe_id"
  end

  create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "employe_id"
    t.integer "meal_id"
    t.index ["employe_id"], name: "index_participants_on_employe_id"
    t.index ["meal_id"], name: "index_participants_on_meal_id"
  end

end
```

relations :

```
class BusinessCompany < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employes
end
class Employe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :business_company
  has_many :menus
  has_many :participants
end
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menus, through: :ingredients_lists
end
class IngredientsList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :menu
end
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  has_many :employes, through: :participants
end
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employe
  has_many :ingredients, through: :ingredients_lists
end
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :employe
end
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: my models generation:
rails g model business_company company_name employes_number:integer pdg

rails g model employe first_name last_name service paiment note:integer status business_company:references

rails g model menu name quantity:integer unit_price:float supply:boolean employe:references

rails g model ingredient name category allergen:boolean

rails g model ingredients_list ingredient:references menu:references

rails g model meal date:date place note:integer menu:references

rails g model participant employe:reference meal:references